error navigating to home screen or initial screen based on current user log in status
Error:
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
the logic is as follow:
if user is new and running the app for the first time, loading screen, splash screen, once daily affirmation that is a fixed affirmation not to be changed (“In the midst of winter, I found there was within me an invincible summer.”)  then initial screen.
if the user is signed up and logged in, running the app should show loading screen, splash screen, once daily affirmation that is pulled from the firestore affirmations randomly then home screen.
enter code here

below is code causing the issue:
// Show flow for logged-in users
void _showAffirmationsAndNavigate() {
  print('Starting _showAffirmationsAndNavigate...');

// Ensure the user state is correct
if (currentUser == null) {
  print('Error: currentUser is null during navigation.');
} else {
  print('User is logged in with UID: ${currentUser!.uid}');
}

// Ensure the right context for navigation
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      print('Navigating to HomeView...');
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeView(
            userId: currentUser!.uid,
            affirmationService: affirmationService,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print('Navigating to InitialScreen for non-logged-in users...');
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const InitialScreen(),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Container(); // Dummy return, as Builder requires a widget to return
  });
});

}
'''
'''

The error occurs because the context used is not linked to the correct Navigator. Using a Builder within a postFrameCallback may result in a context that isn't connected to the Navigator widget.
Solution
Ensure that the correct context is passed directly when calling _showAffirmationsAndNavigate, or use Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true) to access the root navigator.
Refactored code:
void _showAffirmationsAndNavigate(BuildContext context) {
  print('Starting _showAffirmationsAndNavigate...');

  if (currentUser == null) {
    print('Error: currentUser is null during navigation.');
  } else {
    print('User is logged in with UID: ${currentUser!.uid}');
  }

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      print('Navigating to HomeView...');
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeView(
            userId: currentUser!.uid,
            affirmationService: affirmationService,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print('Navigating to InitialScreen for non-logged-in users...');
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const InitialScreen(),
        ),
      );
    }
  });
}


got same error after testing ur code:
I/flutter (24952): User is logged in with UID: JTqXDfFrb8YOVJirM1zdk31UZXV2
I/flutter (24952): Navigating to HomeView...
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
